# validation on the field

Tags: visualforce

Please put validation on this field.

> Will your Organization require a non-disclosure agreement (NDA) in association with this project?

If "Yes" then the field `NDA Signed and Submitted` should have value as Yes or No and cannot be left blank.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: This can be done using a Validation Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your expected Validation Rule

```
AND( ISPICKVAL( Non_Disclosure_Agreement_NDA__c , 'Yes'), ISBLANK( Text(NDA_Signed_and_Submitted__c)))
```